May I change the ICntrl variable in Gaussian 16?
Ive been trying to do energy calculations under the influence of a perturbative field with the BLYP and B3LYP functionals. Using the following input files:
BLYP:
%mem=30000mb
%nproc=30
#P BLYP/aug-cc-pVQZ ExtraLinks=L608 SCF(CONVER=10,nosymm) NoSymmetry  field=read UNITS=BOHR

water

0 1
C   1.454760  -0.000000  0.000000
C   -1.454760  -0.000000  0.000000
H   2.207680  -0.000000  -1.930640
H   2.207560  -1.672010  0.965270
H   2.207720  1.672010  0.965270
H   -2.207720  -1.672010  -0.965280
H   -2.207560  1.672010  -0.965270
H   -2.207680  0.000000  1.930640

-0.006   -0.006   0.0
0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  0.0

            

B3LYP:
%mem=30000mb
%nproc=30
#P B3LYP/aug-cc-pVQZ ExtraLinks=L608 SCF(CONVER=10,nosymm) NoSymmetry  field=read UNITS=BOHR

water

0 1
C   1.454760  -0.000000  0.000000
C   -1.454760  -0.000000  0.000000
H   2.207680  -0.000000  -1.930640
H   2.207560  -1.672010  0.965270
H   2.207720  1.672010  0.965270
H   -2.207720  -1.672010  -0.965280
H   -2.207560  1.672010  -0.965270
H   -2.207680  0.000000  1.930640

-0.006   -0.006   0.0
0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  0.0

After Ive achieved normal termination for both these are the execution times:
BLYP:
Job cpu time:       3 days  7 hours 38 minutes  7.0 seconds.
Elapsed time:       0 days  2 hours 39 minutes 41.4 seconds.

B3LYP:
 Job cpu time:       0 days  0 hours 39 minutes 54.9 seconds.
 Elapsed time:       0 days  0 hours  1 minutes 20.6 seconds.

By comparing the Log files: The ICntrl variable was set to 0 for B3LYP and 500 for BLYP, which seems to be whats making the B3LYP calculations faster. Given below are the excerpts from the log files.
BLYP:
 FoFCou: FMM=F IPFlag=           0 FMFlag=      100000 FMFlg1=           0
         NFxFlg=           0 DoJE=T BraDBF=F KetDBF=T FulRan=T
         wScrn=  0.000000 ICntrl=       500 IOpCl=  0 I1Cent=   200000004 NGrid=           0
         NMat0=    1 NMatS0=      1 NMatT0=    0 NMatD0=    1 NMtDS0=    0 NMtDT0=    0
 Symmetry not used in FoFCou.
 Harris En= -79.9290251867264    

B3LYP:
FoFCou: FMM=F IPFlag=           0 FMFlag=      100000 FMFlg1=           0
         NFxFlg=           0 DoJE=F BraDBF=F KetDBF=F FulRan=T
         wScrn=  0.000000 ICntrl=         0 IOpCl=  0 I1Cent=           0 NGrid=           0
         NMat0=    1 NMatS0=      1 NMatT0=    0 NMatD0=    1 NMtDS0=    0 NMtDT0=    0
 Symmetry not used in FoFCou.

Is there anyway to manually set the ICntrl variable to zero?
Note: The reason for suspecting the ICntrl variable in the log file is that, the B3LYP calculations run slower than BLYP (as expected) when I use the aug-cc-pVTZ basis set. And the ICntrl is set to 500 in both log files.

Is ICntrl specifically the same for this section FoFCou when running with aug-cc-pvtz? My understanding is ICntrl is a name that is reused with various meanings for different routines. As an example see IOp 1/75 here, where ICntrl is mentioned in an entirely different context.

@Tyberius Ive tried to use IOp(1/75=0) to set it to zero. But it still shows a non zero value as mentioned in the question. So I'm not sure how to proceed further

What I'm saying is that ICntrl is likely an entirely internal variable, that changes meaning and value throughout Gaussian. So I suspect it's a variable that in general can't be set by the user.
